# How do I catch a 401 for a partial that I can't access?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app I have a token mechanism for authentication.
Every API call needs the token, otherwise it returns a 401.
Which I can easily handle with a response interceptor.

Now when I am using regular routes, and say the token expire, and I try to visit a partial that requires authentication, How will I trap 401 that I get while routing ?

In cases where the first thing that the page comes is making an API call, I will come to know of token expiry and will logout the user.

I want to be able to stop the user from visiting a view if the token has expired. 
Will response interceptors take care of this scenario also ?

Comment: Response interceptor intercept all request made using service $http which include partial view (ng-include) request too.

Comment: and do they intercept requests when we change whats there in ng-view ?

Comment: Yes. You can put break point and verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to do special processing specific to a partial, you can create a resolve function to check for the defined partial and take appropriate action.  It would look something like:

```
function CheckTemplate() {
    return {
        "TemplateCheck": function ($route, $http) {
            var url = $route.current.templateUrl;

            $http.get(url)
              .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (status===404) {
                  ... // Do what you need to do
                }
              })
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample plunker checking for a 404 on a partial:

http://plnkr.co/edit/4tagMIlcH0jC1A0YODRt?p=preview

Comment: If I don't give a resolver function, while the control go to otherwise ?

Comment: If you don't use resolver function and there is an error loading a templateUrl, you just gonna get an error in your javascript console.  Your user is not going to see anything.